# How can I stop the page reloading whenever a submit button is pressed?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm currently trying to create a system where users of my website can upvote/downvote things. Essentially, the way I'm going about this is by using the following html

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='up' value='up'>
<input type='submit' name='down' value='down'>
</form>
```

Combined with this php:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['up']) ){

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $postid = "";
  $userid = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


  $query = "
  INSERT INTO database.table (postid, ipaddress, vote) VALUES ('$postid', '$userid', '+1')";

  mysqli_query($con, $query);

  mysqli_close($con);

  }

elseif( isset($_POST['down']) ){


  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }


  $postid = "";
  $userid = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


  $query = "
  INSERT INTO database.table (postid, ipaddress, vote) VALUES ('$postid', '$userid', '-1')";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);

  mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

This works to some extent. As I'd hoped, it keeps track of the current vote count. The problem I wish to tackle here is the fact that every time the up/down button is pressed - the page is reloaded. How can I prevent this from happening, and make this process more fluid?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You will need to use Ajax, not possible with only PHP

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: [ajax reference](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. Daniel, could you please explain why I'm vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @JohnSmith Because you are not escaping variables before putting them into your SQL statement. The safer way would be to use prepared statements, instead of fiddling with escaping at the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize that you didn't mention jQuery anywhere in your question, but since you can not do what you are trying to do with pure HTML+PHP, I assume you will sooner or later resort to JS to achieve the effect. jQuery is perfect for this case:

**HTML part**

```
<a class="voter" data-vote="up">Vote up</a>
<a class="voter" data-vote="down">Vote down</a>
```

**jQuery part** ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x64un3u0/5/))

```
$(function(){

  $('.voter').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
    var voteType = $(this).data('vote');
    $.post('/echo/json/', {
        voteType: voteType
    }, function(){
        alert('You have voted');
    });
  });

});
```

**PHP part**

```
$voteType = $_POST['voteType'];

switch($voteType){
    case 'up':
    // Do something
        break;
    case 'down':
    // Do something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'll look into jQuery a bit more. Is this method preferable to using Ajax, as suggested by other posters?

Comment: This _is_ Ajax. The call to `$.post()` is a regular Ajax call in jQuery.